# Add column from one file to another based on multiple matches while retaining unmatched

Tags: bash, join, awk, git-bash

So I am *really* new to this kind of stuff (seriously, sorry in advance) but I figured I would post this question since it is taking me some time to solve it and I'm sure it's a lot more difficult than I am imagining.

I have the file small.csv:

```
id,name,x,y,id2
1,john,2,6,13
2,bob,3,4,15
3,jane,5,6,17
4,cindy,1,4,18
```

and another file big.csv:

```
id3,id4,name,x,y
100,{},john,2,6
101,{},bob,3,4
102,{},jane,5,6
103,{},cindy,1,4
104,{},alice,7,8
105,{},jane,0,3
106,{},cindy,1,7
```

The problem with this is I am attempting to put `id2` of the small.csv into the `id4` column of the big.csv only if the `name` AND `x` AND `y` match. I have tried using different `awk` and `join` commands in Git Bash but am coming up short. Again I am sorry for the newbie perspective on all of this but any help would be awesome. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Sorry, this is what the final desired output should look like:

```
id3,id4,name,x,y
100,{13},john,2,6
101,{15},bob,3,4
102,{17},jane,5,6
103,{18},cindy,1,4
104,{},alice,7,8
105,{},jane,0,3
106,{},cindy,1,7
```

And one of the latest trials I did was the following:

```
$ join -j 1 -o 1.5,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5 <(sort -k2 small.csv) <(sort -k2 big.csv)
```

But I received this error:

```
join: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

Comment: please update the question with a) what code you've tried so far, b) the (incorrect) output you're generating, and c) the desired output

Comment: @jhnc thank you so much, this is very close! Would you mind explaining how this is working? Again, I'm really sorry for being so novice at all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not trivial to solve with `join` but fairly easy with `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, -v OFS=, ' # set input and output field separators to comma

    # create lookup table from lines of small.csv
    NR==FNR {
        # ignore header
        # map columns 2/3/4 to column 5
        if (NR>1) lut[$2,$3,$4] = $5
        next
    }

    # process lines of big.csv
    # if lookup table has mapping for columns 3/4/5, update column 2
    v = lut[$3,$4,$5] {
        $2 = "{" v "}"
    }

    # print (possibly-modified) lines of big.csv
    1

' small.csv big.csv >bignew.csv
```

Code assumes `small.csv` contains only one line for each distinct column 2/3/4.

`NR==FNR { ...; next }` is a way to process contents of the first file argument. (`FNR` is less than `NR` when processing lines from second and subsequent file arguments. `next` skips execution of the remaining awk commands.)

Comment: Wow, this is perfect and a great explanation. Thank you so much for your help and speediness.